# Which time-based partitioning strategy to use for Delta or Iceberg

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, delta-lake, delta-live-tables, apache-iceberg

I am using spark-streaming to ingest live event streams every 5 minutes and append into `delta` or apache `iceberg` table. this table can be ingested and processed by downstream data pipeline or it can be directly used by end consumer to do data analysis.

Every event has `publish_time`, `event_time` and at some point `ingestions_time` and `store_time`.

I can see that `event_time` will be most useful for querying as there can be lot of late arrival data and `event_time` will give updated value every time it's queried. I can partition my `detla` table on event_time for this use case. However, another use case is for `data reprocessing` in event of any failure, data inconsistency. For reprocessing, it makes more sense to reprocess on `store_time` or `ingestion_time`. but if data in only partitioned by `event_time` than querying the detla live table like `select * from table where ingestion_time between date1 and date2` will scan entire table because it's not partitioned by `ingestion_time`.

some solutions I thought of are: 1) I can create two sets of table for each schema. one partitioned by event_time and another by ingestion_time. however, that is harder to maintain.
2) I can partitioned by ingestion_time and during querying I can just use big enough time range to accommodate for late data. however, it's not consumer friendly query.

Is there any better suggestion ?

Example Use cases:

Pipeline A writes processed events to Table A
Pipeline B, C reads from TableA and writes to Table B and Table C respectively.

I want TableA, TableB and TableC to be efficiently queriably by event_time eventhough it's a time series data. In that case, partitioning them by event_time make sense.

Issue is, Many events are coming very late,  upto 6 months old. we still process them and write to correct event_time based partitions in all tables. Caveat is with needs of reprocessing any arbitrary partition data upto this last 6 months. e.g. we need to fix data of Table B and Table C between 08-30-2023 and 09-07-2023 as we know some bug happened after 08-30. but as we allow late data processing during that time frame we could have processed 03-2023 data as well. so we need to reprocess that as well. so we need to collect all the event_time partitions and re-ingest them from TableA for reprocessing.

Comment: Why partition your data at all? Since this is time series data, you can go with Ingestion Time Clustering: https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/11/18/introducing-ingestion-time-clustering-dbr-112.html

Comment: most of our business queries are expressed in event_time and we do have lot of late arrival data. (I added an example)

Answer (score 1):

Your ideas are ok for me, but if a third copy is needed? What then?

I would Z-order on most frequent accessed column in terms of query predicate, and rely on data skipping otherwise.

But your 2nd point on compounded filter for query is also ok.